# Lie product of a two subalgebras

Tags: lie-algebras

Let V and W be subalgebras of a Lie algebra $\mathcal{L}$. I want to show that $[V,W]$ is not always a subalgebra of $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: Let V and W be subalgebras of $\mathcal{L}$ a Lie algebra. I want to show that $[V,W]$ is not always a subalgebra of $\mathcal{L}$. Is it clearer? Thank you very much

Comment: Edit the question and add the explanation there.

Comment: I made a few changes in your question :D

Comment: Yes I saw that thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Consider the Lie algebra $\mathcal L=\{X\in M_4(\mathbb R)\,|\,X^T=-X\}$ with the product $[X,Y]=XY-YX$. A basis of this algebra is given by the matrices $u_{i,j}=e_{i,j}-e_{j,i}$ for $i<j$, where the matrix $e_{i,j}$ has all its coefficients equal to zero but the $(i,j)$-th coefficient which is one.
  As an example
  $$u_{1,2}=\left(
  \begin{array}{cccc}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)\,.$$
  Note the formulae, for $i,j,k$ all different, $$[u_{i,j},u_{j,k}]=-u_{i,k}$$ and for $i,j,k,l$ all different
  $$[u_{i,j},u_{k,l}]=0$$
  allow us to compute easily with those matrices.
- Define the subalgebras $$V=Span(u_{1,2},u_{1,3},u_{2,3})\quad\text{and}\quad W=Span(u_{2,3},u_{2,4},u_{3,4})\,.$$ Then
  $$[V,W]=Span(u_{1,2},u_{1,3},u_{1,4,},u_{2,4},u_{3,4})$$
  Note that $[u_{1,3},u_{1,2}]=u_{2,3}$ and thus $[V,W]$ is not a Lie algebra, since $u_{2,3}\notin[V,W]$.

Well I am not a big fan of my own example so if anyone had anything more simple or more elegant, I would be interested too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't think there is any elegant way to prove it... :)